# Replacing Door Header After Pocket Door Removal

Tags: doors, framing, door-frame, pocket-door

I'm in the middle of opening up a doorway where a pocket door once lived. This is in the first floor of a single story home in a wall that runs along the I-beam (which is below this floor in the basement), so I'm 99% sure it's a loadbearing wall. I know the pocket door framing members weren't really supporting any load even when the pocket door was in there, but I'm still worried about the current configuration . Now that it is removed I can see the pocket door framing was installed by cutting into the header.

My ultimate goal is to just leave this entryway open so I am not planning installing another door. I'm looking for some insight on where I should go from here? Should I hire an engineer to look at it? Should I remove some more of the plaster to see what the header looks like? What type of contractor would I hire if I wanted to get the header replaced?

[image: entry]
[image: closeup]
[image: header1]
[image: header2]

Comment: Just because there’s an “I-beam” under the floor, it doesn’t mean it’s a bearing wall. Can you provide a picture of the attic over this wall?

Answer (score 2):

You indicate there is an “I-beam” located above the pocket door. (I presume that’s a steel I-beam.) The I-beam will support all vertical loads from above and transfer them to the footings. The wood beam above the pocket door is merely for supporting the pocket door.

Comment: Agreed. If the span did not sag with the pocket door and it's flimsy framework, it won't with it removed either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't specific enough. The I-beam is a floor below this opening in the basement. This wall is positioned directly above it. I've clarified in my origin question.